# Transfer executable files from client to server via TCP in C

Tags: c, file-transfer, tcp

I try to transfer an executable file from client to server. The both apps using C and for communication is used TCP/IP.

By now I use the both (client and server) to transfer messages with sockets and read/write.

Can you give me a starting point?

Thanks.

Comment: Server listen(), accept().  Client: connect().  There are millions of examples on web, some of them good.

Comment: Note: if you search for 'C  TCP client server', the top result returned by Google has 'bzero(buffer,256);' - a completely pointless lump of cargo-cult, so take care:)

Comment: Oh... next one has 'printf("Data received: %s",buffer);' on a buffer that is not guaranteed NULL-terminated:((

Comment: NOTE:  correction, don't bother looking up examples on the net, they are rubbish.  Try yourself and post if you encounter problems.

Comment: Try `man 2 bind`. It will give you a sample code at the end of manpage. Or check [this](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_184.html) out.

Comment: After implementing the information available through `Andrew W` asnwer, then google `tftp` (Trivial File Transfer Protocol) which is (relatively) easy to implement and has all the features you would need.    However, If the client and server are on different OSs or any of several other differences,  (like a different CPU) the executable created on the client will not run on the server.

Answer (score 2):

[Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) is one of the best places to start learning about programming a client/server in C.